# Script to scan log file for a keyword for about 30 minutes continuously

Tags: bash, monitoring, redhat

I have a log file with the content below. Let's call it as cpu_usage.out. This log file is generating via cron (1 min interval) to monitor CPU utilization:

```
2023-04-12 12:04: CPU STATISTICS CRITICAL : USED:- 2.52% IDLE:- 97.49%|CpuUsed=2.52;0;1 CpuIdle=97.49;0;1
2023-04-12 12:05: CPU STATISTICS WARNING : USED:- 0.5% IDLE:- 99.50%|CpuUsed=0.5;0;1 CpuIdle=99.50;0;1
2023-04-12 12:06: CPU STATISTICS CRITICAL : USED:- 3% IDLE:- 97.00%|CpuUsed=3;0;1 CpuIdle=97.00;0;1
2023-04-12 12:07: CPU STATISTICS CRITICAL : USED:- 1.53% IDLE:- 98.48%|CpuUsed=1.53;0;1 CpuIdle=98.48;0;1
2023-04-12 12:08: CPU STATISTICS CRITICAL : USED:- 4% IDLE:- 96.00%|CpuUsed=4;0;1 CpuIdle=96.00;0;1
2023-04-12 12:09: CPU STATISTICS CRITICAL : USED:- 3% IDLE:- 97.00%|CpuUsed=3;0;1 CpuIdle=97.00;0;1
```

Now I need to write another script to scan this log file. The script:

1. Detects "CRITICAL" keyword and hold it for 30 minutes which means there must be 30 lines of CRITICAL error in the log continuously
2. If CRITICAL continuously 30 minutes, send an email and terminate the tail command
3. If not do nothing (for example script checks/holds for 29 minutes and the last line (30th minute) is WARNING then script resets back to 0 minute and continues monitor from the beginning)

I have simple script below but I do not know how to monitor the "CRITICAL" keyword for about 30 mins continuously.

```
#!/bin/bash

tail -f /root/cpu_usage.out | while read line
do case "$line" in
    *"CRITICAL"*) echo "$line"
    #*"CRITICAL"*) echo "$line" | mutt -s "The CPU of server $(hostname) is high for about 30 minutes ago" an_email@mail.com;
    ;;
esac
done
```

Also, I have tried the following script but when I ran it, the cursor just hanging there

```
#!/bin/bash


LOGFILE=/root/cpu_usage.out

tail -fn30 $LOGFILE | while read line;
do
CRIT=$(echo $LOGFILE | grep -m 30 "CRITICAL" | wc -l)

if [[ $CRIT -ge 30 ]]
then
  pkill -P $$ tail
  # echo "$line" | mutt -s "The CPU of server $(hostname) is high for about 30 minutes ago" an_email@mail.com
  echo "$line"
fi
done
```

Note: forget first on email part. I will take it later.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```bash
tail -f /root/cpu_usage.out | awk '{if($0~/CRITICAL/) ++c; else c=0} c>=30{exit 7}'
if [ "$?" -eq 7 ]; then
  # mutt ...
fi
# handle other possible exit codes, if you want
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand awk part. Why exit 7? Why return code must be equal to 7? If I want to test for 5 mins, I just replace c>=30 with c>=5 right?